# Facing EC2 high CPU utilization while sending Bulk Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, queue

I'm using Aws SQS with my Laravel project in which when membership owner create a post in memebership I'm sening Twilio SMS, Email and Firebase push Notifications to all the subscriber of that membership. I'm using Laravel Queue Job to send this notifications. The issue is one membership has 5000+ subscribers so it becomes 15000+ notifications so when my server is processing this requests CPU utilization is going 99% for short period of time and users are getting 500 internal server error from nginx.

Post Creation Queue Dispatch

```
$membershipSubscriberIdsChunk = $membershipSubscriber->pluck("id")->chunk(30)->toArray();

                    foreach ($membershipSubscriberIdsChunk as $key => $chunk) {
                        dispatch(new SendPostMailNotificationJob($chunk, $mailPost, $membershipTitle, 0))->onQueue("post-email");
                        dispatch(new SendPostPushNotificationJob($chunk, $mailPost->user->name))->onQueue("post-firebase");
                        dispatch(new SendPostSMSNotificationJob($chunk, $mailPost->user->name))->onQueue("post-sms");
                    }
```

---

Twilio SMS

```
$recipients = $fans->filter(function ($item) {
                if ($item->receive_sms && isset($item->phone) && $item->phone) {
                    $countrycode = $item->country_code ?? '+1';
                    $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $item->phone);
                    $phone = substr($phone, -10);
                    if ($phone) {
                        $item->phoneNumber = $countrycode . $phone;
                        return $item;
                    }
                }
            })->pluck("phoneNumber")->toArray();

            $message = "$this->creatorName has added a new post.";
            $messageOptions = [
                'from' => config('services.twilio.from_number'),
                'body' => $message,
            ];
            Log::channel("post_sms")->info("Twilio SMS Notification Process Start at " . Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            $twilio = new Client(config('services.twilio.sid'), config('services.twilio.auth_token'));
            foreach ($recipients as $key => $recipient) {
                try {
                    Log::channel("post_sms")->info("$key SMS Start");
                    $twilioResponse = $twilio->messages->create($recipient, $messageOptions);
                    Log::channel("post_sms")->info("$key [$recipient] SMS Done.");
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Log::channel("post_sms")->error("$recipient has an error." . $e->getMessage());
                }
            }
            Log::channel("post_sms")->info("Twilio SMS Notification Process Completed at " . Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ".\n");

            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Sent Request to Twilio."
            ]);
```

---

Firebase Push Notification

```
$subscribers = MembershipSubscriber::with(["fan"])->whereIn("id", $this->membershipSubscriber)->get();
        Log::channel('post_firebase')->info("Firebase Notification Process Start at " . Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $message = $this->creatorName . " has added a new post.";
        $title = "New Post Added";

        if ($subscribers->count()) {
            foreach ($subscribers as $key => $subscriber) {
                if (isset($subscriber->fan) && isset($subscriber->fan->apn_token) && $subscriber->fan->apn_token != "") {
                    $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
                    $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60 * 20);

                    $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($title);
                    $notificationBuilder->setBody($message)->setSound('default');

                    $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
                    $dataBuilder->addData(['subscriber_id' => $subscriber->id, 'type' => 'post']);

                    $option = $optionBuilder->build();
                    $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
                    $data = $dataBuilder->build();

                    $token = $subscriber->fan->apn_token;
                    $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($token, $option, $notification, $data);
                    $responseData = [
                        "numberSuccess" => $downstreamResponse->numberSuccess(),
                        "numberFailure" => $downstreamResponse->numberFailure(),
                        "numberModification" => $downstreamResponse->numberModification(),
                    ];
                    Log::channel('post_firebase')->info("response for token.", $responseData);
                }
            }
            Log::channel('post_firebase')->info("Firebase Notification Process Completed at " . Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n");
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Push Notifications sent successfully"
            strong text]);
```

---

Email

```
$fans = MembershipSubscriber::with(["fan"])->whereIn("id", $this->membershipSubscriber)->get()->pluck("fan");
        $fans = $fans->where("receive_email", 1);
        if ($fans->count()) {
            Log::channel('post_mail')->info("Mail Notification Main Job Start at " . Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            Notification::send($fans, (new PostCreatedEmailNotification($this->membershipPost, $this->membershipTitle, $this->jobDelay)));
            Log::channel('post_mail')->info("Mail Notification Main Job Completed at " . Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ".\n");
        } else {
            Log::channel('post_mail')->error("Mail Notification Fan User Not Found.");
        }
```

Comment: well.. what did you expect? But you shouldn't send these notifications from a frontend server anyway...

Comment: @HonkderHase I'm willing to use any third party service/api provider. but don't know much about any service provide.

Comment: I think what Honk is suggesting is that you spin up another server to handle backend tasks like these notifications without impacting frontend services. I would second that, or at least enacting some level of control over how many backend processes are created. There's also the option of moving the notification code into an AWS Lambda that runs only on-demand, though you'll probably want to do some preliminary tests to guage costs on that before blasting 15k notifications through it on whatever frequency that that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following steps:

1. Measure the performance and set the optimal limit of sending messages per minute based on CPU usage. So it will take a bit longer to send all 15000 notifications but you will not get 503 on forontend. It can be 500 or 1000 depending on your machine CPU and time it takes to send one notification.
2. You can run the jobs on different app server so background processes do not affect your users. But this will require infrastructure adjustments if you have only one machine.

It's a good practice to have a separate server to handle cron jobs / message queues / other "async/queued" processes